# Sql function to search and remove

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, plsql

I have few below scenarios,Can any one tell me how to remove C or -1C or -2C etc..

I am getting  data in different ways

```
Examples:  test1C : To extract as test1

           test1-1C :to extract as test1

           test1-2C : to extract as test1.
           testC1C : to extract as testC1
           testCC: to extract as testC
```

I tried with substr and instr functions and not able to thumbs up. In above examples expected data not comes always as with length '5'.Data varies,but some times data appended with 'C' or '-1C' or '-2C .

Regards,

Chaitu

Comment: Can you give us some real world examples rather then just what you have? There are winning solutions below, however I have a suspicion that you will have alot more complicated data that may render those answers useless...

Comment: Robert H:Here complexity is,If data has C or -1C or -2C or -1-1C .Then it should remove all these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just

```
regexp_replace(str, '-[^-]*|C$', '')
```

e.g.

```
SQL> with data as (select 'test1C' str, 'test1' expected from dual
  2                union all
  3                select 'test1-1C', 'test1' from dual
  4                union all
  5                select 'test1-2C', 'test1' from dual
  6                union all
  7                select 'testC1C', 'testC1' from dual
  8                union all
  9                select 'testCC', 'testC' from dual)
 10  select str, expected, regexp_replace(str, '-[^-]*|C$', '') actual
 11  from data;

STR      EXPECT ACTUAL
-------- ------ ----------
test1C   test1  test1
test1-1C test1  test1
test1-2C test1  test1
testC1C  testC1 testC1
testCC   testC  testC

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks DazzaL.Simple and best answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. select replace(column_name, 'C', '') from table_name -- this works in sybase fine
2. select replace ((select replace(column_name, '-', '') from table_name), C,'')
3. select replace((select replace(column_name, '-', '') from table_name), C,'')

Comment: :i need a common solution.i gave only samples.

Comment: If need common solution use Left

Comment: By the way you can also use LEN function to find the length of the string and based on length you can write CASE statements or IF/Else blocks. Like CASE WHEN LEN(COLUMN) = 7 THEN select replace(column_name, 'C', '') from table_name WHEN ... END

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply trying to extract the first 5 characters then Substr should work just fine. i.e. SUBSTR(Column_Name,1,5) of all the above will give you "test1". Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you give better examples?  Can you better explain (in the question, not comments) what the pattern is?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just take the 5 first characters?

```
left(val, 5)
```

Let me guess that the rule is:  if there is a hyphen, everything before the hyphen; if there is a 'C", then everything before the 'C'; otherwise everything:

```
left(val, (case when locate('-', val) > 0 then locate('-', val) - 1
                when locate('C', val) > 0 then length(val) - locate('C', reverse(val)) - 1
                else length(val)
            end))
```

Whether this works for distinguishing between upper and lower case c's may depend on your collating sequence.

Comment: Left is good solution and he can use replace before left as well to remove '-' and make them equal width

Comment: @Gordon:Not sure length of data .so we cant hard code length i.e 5.

Comment: Then it is better you post some of the real data here so we can understand question better. Here it seemed like before 1C, -1C and -2C length of data is same and string is same. You can also try Distinct to find the how many different combinations of length you really have if they are variable and a lot as well as free text then your options are really not that much because whatever we can suggest is based upon set pattern of data.

Comment: @Gordon:That's right.if there is '-'  then everything before '-' data should display.otherwise if there is 'C',everything before 'C' should display,if there is C is original data,then it will give issue?

Comment: @Gordon:What if data itslef has C in it.Ex:teCst1C

Comment: Could you please edit your question with the correct rules and better examples?

Comment: @user1726550 You are asking for a solution for an arbitrary set of rules that you have yet to fully explain, as well as using examples in your question which are different then the examples in your comments. You need to fix your question as Gordon has asked, as his solution is correct based upon your examples.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to create temporary table, dump all your data in their. Then use update function to update values there. The steps would be the following

1. Create temporary table
2. Write data to temporary table
3. Update temporary table. Update column values as you need.

Answer (score 0):

What about this query?

```
select substring_index(substring_index('test1-2C', 'C', 1), '-', 1)
```

---

**Function:**

```
create function mytrim(p_text varchar(100))
returns varchar(100)
begin
  set @text = reverse(p_text);
  set @l = locate('-', @text);
  if @l > 0 then
    return reverse(substring(@text, @l + 1));
  elseif locate('C', @text) > 0 then
    return reverse(substring(@text, 2));
  else
    return p_text;
  end if;
end
```

Comment: :yes it has to check only last character of the data.

Comment: At the end, I'd write a function.

Comment: tried with tesCt1,returned tes.so it also failed.it should always look for end of character 'C'